# Why doesnt localhost point to my Ubuntu apache webserver?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, webserver, localhost

as the title says I am really stuck wondering why localhost can't connect to the server in my browser and show me the default 'It Works!' page as described in many tutorials ( after just installing apache2 in the terminal). The ip address provided in 'ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'' command does redirect me to that page, but not through just 'localhost'.

Ive searched a lot but what it may be due to? The Virtual Machine network settings?(It is now on bridged network)? Any configurations inside the ubuntu VM? Can someone provide a simple step by step guide on what to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

do a > `tailf /var/log/apache2/error.log` what do you have in there? this has nothing to do with your internet connection or VM Networked Bridge.

Have you tried `sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2?` 
then `sudo apt-get install apache2?`

after that issue> `ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'`

to find your local ip address

then go to the browser

```
http://your-ip/welcome.html
```

By default this is where your apache2 log sits on Ubuntu,

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

have you issued: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start`? you need to start the webserver in order for you to access it.

**//localhost issue**

your localhost doesn't work because you don't have 
this line in `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

If it is not there, add it.

you can use emacs, vi, or gedit or even notepad, locate the file and make sure its in there. this should get you going.

Comment: Hi, I tried all of these but I get this message now: 'Not Found

The requested URL /welcome.html was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.111 Port 80'

Comment: Also, how do I get the log into a text file for you to show?

Comment: Ah, I literally had the url 'welcome.html' and it had to be index.html. Now I get to the 'it works' page through that ip, but why doesnt 'localhost' work?

Comment: see my answer, i edited the part and tells you how to fix the ://localhost issue

Comment: That line is already in my /etc/hosts/ file. And how do you mean? How can I get it from my Ubuntu terminal to a textfile in my host?

Comment: if you're in the gui and you have the terminal open issue > sudo emacs /etc/hosts -nw (nw, no window) it will bring up the file to the terminal. have you tried restarting apache? sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop | then start?

Comment: can you post your /etc/hosts file contents. try to ping localhost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67030/discussion-between-unixmiah-and-user3660293).